# How to loop through all the form elements inside a table row using jquery?

Tags: jquery

How do I get all the form elements inside a table row? Each row can have many tds with each td having any number of input or select elements.

Please help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```
$('#myTableRow').find('input, select, textarea').each(function()
{
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It will not return any other elements like span and divs inside the tr?

Comment: Sorry, the above will select any elements. One sec, and I'll fix it.

Comment: Fixed to select form elements.

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
$("table tr :input").each(function () {
    //your logic here
    //alert(this.tagName)
})
```

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ipr101/qMS7P/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
$('table input, table textarea, table select').each(function() { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

For table rows you could select all inputs like this:

```
var myInputFields = $("#myTable tr input[type='text']");
```

This will select only inputs, no matter how many levels deep into a table row - so you can have rows which have div>s, p>s and other stuff wrapped around the input>s.

You could use jQuery.each or a simple for i=0->myInputFields.length to loop through all the input fields.

```
myInputFields.each(function(i,v){
   var v = $(v);
   console.debug(v.html(),v.val());
});
```

You could extend the selector for more input/textareas etc easily like the example in simoncereska's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the inputs in a specific row:

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr id="the_row">
    <td><input type="text" value="1"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="2"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="3"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="4"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#the_row :input").each(function () {
  console.log(this.value);
});
```

(Note: The [`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) selector matches all `input`, `select`, `textarea` and `button` elements)

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/WuamV/